# Crash when using the customcellview in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

My first IOS program crash when i try to using my custom TableCellView.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
AuthorizeTableCell *cell = (AuthorizeTableCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AuthorizeCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"AuthorizeTableCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0 ];                
}

cell.batchIDLabel.text = [[self.authorizeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"batchID"];
cell.amountIDLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.authorizeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"amount"]] ;

return cell;
}
```

The AuthorizeTableCell Class only contain 2 label and 1 button in the TableCellView. i have make sure that the 3 component have been dealloc in the class. The program run correctly if i use the standard TableCellView. Can someone give me some advice?

thx
cap

Comment: What are the errors in log terminal ? can you post stack trace ? From the above code it looks like okay

Comment: Which is your customcell's parent class? UITableViewCell?

Comment: i turn on the NSZombieEnabled = YES
And the console show
                                                   
*** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: @interface AuthorizeTableCell : UITableViewCell

Comment: Then comment all the releases in custom cells dealloc...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that i have run the wrong command in the custom cells dealloc

```
-void dealloc {
[component1 dealloc];
[component2 dealloc];
[component3 dealloc];
[super dealloc];
}
```

after i change it into 'release' , it works fine ^_^
thx